# Got $e^{-x}=\cos(ix)$ from Euler's formula. Where is my mistake?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, exponential-function

When I was messing around with Euler's formula, I came across this: $$e^{ix}=\cos(x)+\sin(x)i$$ Then, let $x$ be an imaginary value, $ix$, so then: $$e^{i(ix)}=\cos(ix)+\sin(ix)i$$ which we can simplify to $$e^{-x}=\cos(ix)+\sin(ix)i,$$ but since $e^{-x}$ is a real value for all real inputs, then $\sin(ix)i$ must be equal to $0$. so that means that $$e^{-x}=\cos(ix)$$ This doesn't seem right, so could someone please point out where I made a mistake?

Comment: $i\sin (ix) = i(i \sinh x) = -\sinh x$

Comment: Why should $\sin(ix)$ be real?

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Since $\cos ix=\cosh x$ and $\sin ix=i\sinh x$, $\cos ix+i\sin ix=\cosh x-\sinh x$.

Comment: You assumed that both $\sin(ix)$ and $\cos(ix)$ are real. Based on this assumption, you have concluded that the only real part of $\cos(ix) + i \sin(ix)$ is $\cos(ix)$. The mistake in this reasoning is your initial assumption.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $a+bi=\lambda\in\Bbb R$, with $a,b\in\Bbb R$ then, indeed, you must have $a=\lambda$ and $b=0$. But, in the equality$$e^{-x}=\cos(ix)+\sin(ix)i,$$you have no reason to assume that $\cos(ix),\sin(ix)\in\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 7):

You are right to say that $e^{-x}$ is a real value for all real inputs. But you seem to assume that $\sin(ix)$ is also a real value for all real inputs. Maybe this assumption is hasty...

Answer (score 6):

> $$e^{-x}=\cos(ix)+\sin(ix)i,$$ but since $e^{-x}$ is a real value for all real inputs, then $\sin(ix)i$ must be equal to $0$.

That does not follow unless you know that $\sin(ix)$ is real, and there's no reason to think that.

$$
\sin(ix) = \frac{e^{i(ix)} - e^{-i(ix)}}{2i} = \frac{e^{-x} - e^x}{2i}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

You assumed $\sin(ix)=0$, but according to the formula
\begin{equation}
\sin(x)=\mathrm{i}\frac{e^{-\mathrm{i}x}-e^{\mathrm{i}x}}{2},
\end{equation}
($\sin(x)$ is sometimes **defined** this way for all $x\in\mathbf{C}$),
\begin{equation}
\sin(\mathrm{i}x)=\mathrm{i}\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2},
\end{equation}
and thus this is true if and only if $x=0$ (if $x=0$, $\cos(ix)=1$ and there is no contradiction).

I guess you assumed this because you know that a complex number is real if and only if its imaginary part is zero, but $\sin(\mathrm{i}x)$ is **not** the imaginary part of $\cos(\mathrm{i}x)+\mathrm{i}\sin(\mathrm{i}x)$.